# macro always throw "UnmatchedDelimiter" if given anon function

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I wrote a macro to handle http response

```
(defmacro defhandler
  [name & args]
  (let [[docstring args] (if (string? (first args))
                           [(first args) (next args)]
                           [nil args])
        args (apply hash-map :execute-if true (vec args))]
    `(do
       (def ~name
         (with-meta (fn [scope# promise#]
                      (let [e# (:execute-if ~args)
                            ei# (if (fn? e#)
                                  (e# scope#)
                                  (boolean e#))]
                        (when ei#
                          (.then promise# (fn [result#]
                                            (let [{:strs [http-status# value#]} result#
                                                  the-func# ((keyword http-status#) ~args)]
                                              (the-func# scope# value#))))))) {:structure ~args}))
       (alter-meta! (var ~name) assoc :doc ~docstring))))
```

So I can do

```
(defhandler my-handler
  :200 (fn [$scope value] (set! (.-content $scope) value)))
```

But that throws "UnmatchedDelimiter" at line 1, but if I try with a named function:

```
(defn my-func [$scope value] (set! (.-content $scope) value))

(defhandler my-handler 
  :200 my-func)
```

It works ok. I'm just curious, is that a normal behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

That is not the behavior I see when I try your example, nor does it seem very likely. I suggest checking that the forms you pasted here are *exactly* the ones that produce an error; I suspect your actual anonymous function included one too many `)`s.

Comment: What is the behaviour you see?

Comment: That's odd. I also try by copying the code on this page and still give me the error. Anyway, thanks for your response.